# Convert Variadic Template Function to many concrete functions

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Is there a compiler flag or technique to force the generation of one non-variadic function for each call to a variadic function template with a unique signature?

In the following example, the compiler creates variadic templates with signatures `int (int, float, double)`, `int (float, double)` and `int (double)`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class IntT, class argsf>
IntT SumArgs(const argsf& firstArg)
{
    return static_cast<IntT>(firstArg);
}

template<class IntT, class argsf, class ...argst>
IntT SumArgs(const argsf& firstArg, const argst&... restArgs)
{
    return static_cast<IntT>(firstArg + SumArgs<IntT>(restArgs...));
}

int main()
{
    cout<<"Sum result: " << SumArgs<int>(1, 2.f, 3.5);
    return 0;
}
```

The first two remain variadic. However, in some circumstances, it might be desirable to avoid the overhead of variadic functions and instead create a unique function definition for each signature listed above. Is there a way to get compilers to do this? The alternative is to write versions of the function that explicitly use 0, 1, 2 ... n arguments for some reasonably large n and duplicate the code by hand, but ideally the compiler could do this heavy-lifting for us.

Comment: Please avoid `using namespace std;`.  It is considered bad practice.  See [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)  (In fact, it saves you about -15 characters in this case.)

Comment: I think you misunderstand how templates work.  They are just a recipie.  When you compile the code, the compiler will stamp out concrete functions (`int (int, float, double)`, `int (float, double)` and `int (double)`) from the templates.

Comment: Why do you think there is any overhead at all with templates?

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm running code in an environment where variadic  functions are prohibited. The generated code that is compiled after templates are filled in is still a variadic function, since the compiler backend complains that about using a variadic function. I'm using the ComputeCPP SDK for Ubuntu.

Comment: I see.  I think you would need a tool for this, since the compiler will reject the code no matter what.  Does that mean your compiler does not support C++11?

Comment: Hm, 'variadic function' is actually something different, like printf; those functions are using the ellipsis syntax, which is far older than variadic templates: `void f(int someThing, ...);`

Comment: The compiler supports C++11 and C++14, so it compiles fine if I do not use the code from a path that uses the device code generation backend. This backend has restrictions that prevent dynamic memory allocation, so no variadic functions.

Comment: A variadic template requires no dynamic allocation.  They become real function parameters, unlike a variadic function like `printf`

Comment: @Artyer thanks! Maybe it is a bug in the implementation, since I'm not using any traditional variadic functions. I'll experiment a little more and see if all are disallowed or only those with certain shapes.

Comment: There is no variadic function here anywhere. A variadic template is not a variadic function and will never be instantiated into a variadic function (if you use a proper/correct C++ compiler). Perhaps the "compiler" you're using converts the variadic templates into variadic functions??

Comment: Woooops, I had code in the device path that was throwing exceptions and was causing the backend to fail with this error :( I recently added a bunch of variadic function templates so assumed that these were the cause, but it appears that they are fine. This question was helpful in clarifying how these work, thank you for taking the time to respond!

Comment: You have wrote: `since the compiler backend complains that about using a variadic function`. Please edit question and provide that information adding info about environment, compiler and exact error message you see.

Comment: Here is the final code: https://github.com/BenjaminTrapani/FunGPU. The variadic template functions are in PortableMemPool.hpp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++17 introduces fold expressions which are (hopefully) exactly what you are looking for:

```
template <class R, class... Args>
constexpr R SumArgs(const Args&... args)
{
    return static_cast<R>((args + ...)); // fold expression
}
```

If you don't want to use variadic templates, you can use an `initializer_list`:

```
template <class R, class T>
constexpr R SumArgs(std::initializer_list<T> args)
{
    return std::accumulate(args.begin(), args.end(), R{});
}
```

Comment: Or, if you want to enforce at least one summand (as question): `return (static_cast<R>(firstArg) + ... + static_cast<R>(restArgs));`

Comment: @Aconcagua The fold expression fires if `args` is empty, FWIW.

Comment: What you write is correct but don't seems to me that respond to the question. The OP problem (she (or he) clarify it in a comment) is that is "running code in an environment where variadic template functions are prohibited".

Comment: @max66 The fact that variadic templates are prohibited changes the problem fundamentally ... I shall provide the alternative solution and let the OP judge, I guess.

Comment: I see... could works if the list of arguments is (or can be converted in) a list of elements of the same type. In this case, also the good-old `std::vector` could be used, if the OP can't use C++11.